# Syntax for Ruby DBI with Oracle database and schema's

Tags: ruby, oracle, schema, dbi

I used to be able to use dbi like `db.do("select * from table")` and get the results I needed, however I now have to use a schema to access the tables I need and the above line would give me the dbi error:

```
DBI::ProgrammingError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    from stmt.c:312:in oci8lib.so
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-oci8-2.0.6-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:288:in `exec'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-oci8-2.0.6-x86-mingw32/lib/dbd/OCI8.rb:354:in `execute'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/base_classes/database.rb:96:in `execute'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/base_classes/database.rb:114:in `do'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/database.rb:106:in `do'
    from (irb):35
    from ♥:0
```

I can access the table with this `db.do("select * from schema.table")` however I'd rather not change every line from `table` to `schema.table`.

Please tell me how I get my scripts to work without changing ever line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running db.do("SET SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME") before running any other statements

Edit: The correct syntax is :
db.do("ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=SCHEMA_NAME")

This will change your default schema to the one you want to work on for the duration of the session

Comment: Thanks for the reply SimonV.  When I try this command I get `DBI::DatabaseError: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`

Comment: Try with this syntax: ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=SCHEMA_NAME

Comment: Sweet, looks like it did the trick.  Can you alter your main answer so I can mark it as the Answer?